# FXML file doesn't open from Jar file

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a chat app. User needs to `login` and when he clicks on `start button`, chat window will be displayed.

The jar file works fine when I run it on my computer or someone's computer. But, after login, when user clicks on `start up` it fails to load fxml file and throws the following exception :

```
javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
```

I use the same code to load `login` and `start` fxml files.

I use the following code to load the fxml :

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("view/chat.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setController(this);
try {
      this.yofrndlist_obj = new YoFriendList();
      this.my_ip = new MyLocalIP();
      this.scene = LoginController.scene;
      parent = (StackPane) fxmlLoader.load();
} catch (IOException e) {
      new LogWriter(logger, e);
}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the location of the `fxml` in your project structure? Moreover, can you make sure that you fxmls are present along with your class files in the bin directory.

Comment: yeah. all fxmls are located in separate package along with all class files.there have no problem in project structure

Comment: Can you still edit and add your project structure in the question?

Comment: i cant add image because of less reputation

Comment: can u tell me what should be the project structure ?

Comment: Add a link to your image and we will edit it for you ;)

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/488gficgj/

Comment: dont think about package name